# Connect to Postgres in DataGrip

Tags: postgresql, docker, datagrip

I try to connect to my Postgres database built by `docker` in `DataGrip` but I get connection error.

Here is my `application.yml` file:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    database: POSTGRESQL
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/postgis_db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
```

Here is `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgis_db
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    expose:
      - 5432
    networks:
      - app-network

  geolocation-service:
    image: geolocation-service
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - app-network

volumes:
  db:

networks:
  app-network:
```

DataGrip connection settings:

[image]

And the error I get:

[image]

Does anybody knows how to solve this?

Connecting to this db by shell works fine:

```
docker exec -it a37 psql -U postgres postgis_db
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file, you have to allow connections from all hosts for this user, by default it is restricted to localhost.